# Iterate backwards using iterators

Tags: c++, string, iterator

For simplification of my question i will use `std::string::iterator` and `std::string::reverse_iterator` but the question is about iterators in general.

Is there any particular reason to iterate backwards using the following loop:

```
std::string s = "something";
for (std::string::reverse_iterator it = s.rbegin(); it != s.rend(); ++it)
```

rather than this one:

```
std::string s = "something";
std::string::iterator it = in.end();
while(it!=in.begin())
{
    it--;
   //do something
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Reverse iterators allow you to reuse generic code because you can treat them like normal iterators, calling `++` to go backwards. For example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

template <class Iterator>
void printAll(Iterator begin, Iterator end)
{
    for (auto it = begin; it != end; ++it) // ++ can mean "go backwards"
                                           // if Iterator is a reverse
                                           // iterator
    {
        std::cout << *it << "\n";
    }
}

int main()
{
    std::string s = "123";
    printAll(s.begin(), s.end());   // prints 1, 2, 3
    printAll(s.rbegin(), s.rend()); // prints 3, 2, 1
}
```

Notice how you do not need to write a reverse version for `printAll` using `--`.

Now, consider all the functions in `<algorithm>`. The existence of reverse iterators means that you can easily use all of them in a reverse manner. For example, there is [`std::copy_n`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy_n), but not `std::reverse_copy_n`, but with reverse iterators, it's not necessary, because you can write something like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

int main()
{
    std::string input = "abcdef";
    std::string output;
    std::string output_reversed;

    // copy the first 3 elements:
    std::copy_n(input.begin(), 3, std::back_inserter(output));

    // copy the first 3 elements going backwards, starting at the last one:
    std::copy_n(input.rbegin(), 3, std::back_inserter(output_reversed));

    std::cout << output << "\n";          // prints abc
    std::cout << output_reversed << "\n"; // prints fed
}
```

For non-generic code, such as in your question, it's more of a style issue, with few technically sound arguments to prefer one over the other.

Comment: This is a good answer, because it does actually not just answer the question (to which a perfectly correct answer would have been *No*), but the more fundamental (and better) question *What's the point of `reverse_iterator`?*

Answer (score 1):

Since begin() points to the first member, and end() points to the member next to the last, that is all about clean code (since in case of using not reverse iterators you would do iterator decrement first, then the code you want to execute, **then you will compare iterator with begin(), but it is wrong,** since begin() points to an existing first element.

[std::vector::end() at cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/end/)

Comment: `in.begin()-1` No, no, no, a thousand times no.

Comment: I did not recommend it, but it can work out sometimes.

Comment: @sandyre I believe that my while loop does what it is expected to do since i tested it.

Comment: So the main reason is that the first way is more elegant and clear than the second?

Comment: @theVoid Basically yes. Your loop works just fine, sorry for my mark, deleted it.

Comment: @sandyre: What do you mean it can "work out sometimes"? `in.begin() - 1` is undefined behaviour. So that's a very dangerous definition of "to work out sometimes", to say the least.